# Ações Padrões do Windows Form [Minimizar - Maximizar - Fechar]

Tags: c#, visual-studio

*Eu estou usando o visual studio - Windows Forms, e por padrão o form tem os botões de controle do form de **"Minimizar"** outro de **"Maximizar"** e outro para **Fechar** o form que é um **"X"**,
Eu preciso manipular as ações dentro deles, mais especificamente quero que o programa ao minimizar de **hide** no form.
Algum conhece alguma forma de fazer isso ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode manipular o evento Resize:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
            this.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Caso você queira definir isso para todos os forms, você precisa fazer um form de base que deverá ser herdado pelos outros.

Comment: Perfeito, Muito Obrigado.